# Retrieving original timestamp of files after "copying" them to a new directory in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-transfer, file-management

I'm a musician and I use my phone(android) all the time to record musical ideas every now and then. The catch here is that - it was almost like a diary for me as it linked recordings with date/time.

I had close to 1000 recordings and I recently had planned to switch to a new phone. So naturally, I had to carry all the old data to the new phone. But the new files have completely lost their original date timestamps. On the brighter side, yes - I have all the content with me, but it's no more linked to their original datetime stamps. It breaks my heart as it was so much more than just recordings to me - as it used to tell me about the state of time/life when I'd written some of it.

If there is a way to retrieve the original date/time of the files - please let me know.

PS: My old phone is completely wiped off now. The only copy I have now is the copy that I did from my old phone to my windows PC.

Comment: What file format are the recordings?

Comment: *.mp3, *.m4a, *.wav

Comment: If you are lucky the recording date will be stored in the files metadata. [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) will show the metadata for mp3 and m4a files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that tip! 

Also from my research today, looks like windows will retain the "last modified" date as it is from the copied source unless the file was modified after copying. And sound files cannot be modified that easily like text files so I'm hoping the last modified time-stamps would be there reflecting the 'create date'. 

Shall update the thread once I get home and find out.